# Calculate distance of one point in DF with all other points in R

Tags: r, loops, distance

I have a dataframe with around 10,000 points. I want to find to take the first point and check its distance from the second point onwards and if the distance is less than "d" (variable), I remove these two points from df and perform this activity with the first point of the new df.
This is done till there are only 2 points left in the dataframe.

It takes a lot of time. Is there a time-efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your points exist in 2D space (e.g. Euclidean), then you can use the [Cluster package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cluster/versions/2.1.0/topics/daisy):

```
library(cluster)
data(agriculture)

##  Dissimilarities using Euclidean metric
d.agr <- daisy(agriculture, metric = "euclidean")
as.matrix(d.agr)
```

The final matrix will give you the "distance" between each point, according to the metric you set (Euclidean in the above example).